# Why Rust compiler is not smart enough to detect the variable and function with same name?

Tags: function, rust

I'm trying to access a function by passing an argument but the argument and function name both are same,

```
fn main(){
    let name = "xyz";
    println!("name: {:?}", name(name));}

fn name(y: &str)-> &str{
    y}
```

the output says it is expresion and need function to resolve, actually it is a function and it can be resolved by changing the function name, but for now I want to know why is compiler not detecting the function?

```
error[E0618]: expected function, found `&str`
2 |     let name = "xyz";
  |         ---- `&str` defined here
3 |     println!("name: {:?}", name(name));
  |                            ^^^^------
  |                            |
  |                            call expression requires function
```

Comment: Because functions are first-class values? That is, there can be a variable containing a function reference which can be used either as a parameter or as a "function name".

Comment: @MatsKindahl TBF you can have first-class functions and multiple namespaces e.g. the so-called lisp-2 systems.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know why is compiler not detecting the function?

Because there's nothing to detect.

Rust doesn't segregate functions into a separate namespace, for the most part a function is just a value like any other. Because `name` could just as well be a closure (which is callable), or a method reference e.g.

```rust
fn foo() {} // "regular" function
fn main() {
    let foo = foo; // local reference to the function
    let foo = Foo::foo; // UFCS
    let foo = || {}; // anonymous function
}
```

In fact, while implementing the traits remain unstable, it should eventually be possible to make *anything* into a "function" (Python calls this concept "callables") by implementing the Fn/FnMut/FnOnce traits.

Answer (score 1):

A function is a variable. when you use that same variable name in a new scope, it uses that new declaration throughout that scope. So within the `main()` function, you're overwriting the variable `name` with the new value, `"xyz"`. Your code is essentially `"xyz"("xyz")`.

As another example, what would this code print?

```rust
fn name() {
    println!("hi");
}

fn main() {
    fn name() {
        println!("bye");
    }
    name();
}
```

It would print `"bye"`, since it's calling the *local* function `name`.

The notable exception to this is re-declaring a function within the same scope (whether it's a top level or within a function context):

```rust
fn name() {
    println!("a");
}
fn name() {
    println!("b");
}
fn main() {
    fn name() {
        println!("c");
    }
    fn name() {
        println!("d");
    }
    name();
}
```

This will give you two errors, one for each scope where you've declared it twice.

```
  |
1 | fn name() {
  | --------- previous definition of the value `name` here
...
4 | fn name() {
  | ^^^^^^^^^ `name` redefined here
  |
  = note: `name` must be defined only once in the value namespace of this module

error[E0428]: the name `name` is defined multiple times
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
8  |     fn name() {
   |     --------- previous definition of the value `name` here
...
11 |     fn name() {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ `name` redefined here
   |
   = note: `name` must be defined only once in the value namespace of this block
```